# Modified Spectroscopic Notation (Shankar)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, notation, spectroscopy

In Shankar's Chapter on addition of angular momentum in his *Principles of Quantum Mechanics* (Chapter 15 of the 2nd edition), he includes the section attached after describing the basic strategy for obtaining the CG coefficients.

What I'm afraid I don't follow is what the inclusion of the superscript tells us. In particular, if we are saying that the electron is in an eigenstate of total angular momentum (j=3/2 in the example), then it is not a spin projection (quantum number $m_s$) eigenstate. So what is the superscript telling us? I suppose there is a one-to-one correspondence between 2s+1 and s (the spin angular momentum quantum number), so does the 2s+1 just tell us about the statistics of the particle? I have a feeling that this interpretation is almost certainly wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the same example as given in the book
$${}^{2S+1}L_J={}^{2}P_{3/2}$$
This implies $j=3/2$ and letter $P$ denote that  $l=1$ from here it's trivial to see
$s=j-l=1/2$ which can be seen from the fact that $2s+1=2\Rightarrow s=1/2$.

The $S$ is the total spin which might not be a statistic of the particles for a multiparticle system. For example the second example
$${}^{2S+1}L_J={}^{1}S_{0}$$

$S\Rightarrow l=0$ (total orbital angular momentum) and $j=0$ total angular momentum and $2s+1=1\rightarrow s=0$ that is total spin angular momentum which doesn't denote the statistics of the particles.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I sort of see what you're saying, but I'm not sure I agree with your statement that $s = j-l$ (not true in general). If I'm understanding you correctly, you're largely saying that the superscript is used for the one-to-one correspondence between 2s+1 and s. But what then is meant by the multiplicity due to spin projections?

Comment: See @roshoka answer! that I think should enough!

Answer (score 0):

$2S+1$ is the multiplicity, meaning how many degenerate states there are for a given $S$ since $-S \leq M_s \leq S$ (where $M_s$ is the spin projection number). For $S=1$, $M_s = -1, 0, 1$. So the superscript is $2(1) + 1 = 3$ for the $3$ degenerate states in spin.

Comment: I guess my confusion is that, in the total angular momentum eigenbasis ($J^2$ eigenbasis) we do not have states of definite $m_s$?